# Adding Listview in Activity

Tags: android, listview

I want to add ListView as component in my Activity which uses LinearLayout.
I tried simple approach as well as suggestion mentioned in [Embedding a sized ListView in activity - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953424/embedding-a-sized-listview-in-activity-android)

But app crashes on Android 2.2 emulator. I can not inherit my class from ListActivity because I want to include some more components.

Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Post your LogCat error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Declare `ListView` control in xml file which you are setting as `contentView` and then do Mapping of that `Listview` in your class file.

2) If you don't want to use `ListView` in XMl file then use `ListActivity`

3) If you don't want to use `ListActivity` and also Don't want to use `ListView` from Xml file then Make a Dynamic `ListView` in class file and 
set that `listView` as `contentView`